# Determining button boundries with terminal IO in non-canonical mode

Tags: c, linux, input, terminal, posix

I'm trying to understand how terminal I/O works.

When a terminal is placed in non-canonical mode like so (missing error handling):

```
struct termios term_original, term_current;
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term_original);
term_current = term_original;
term_current.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN | ECHO);
term_current.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | IGNBRK | IGNCR | INLCR | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON | PARMRK);
term_current.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
term_current.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;
term_current.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSADRAIN, &term_current);
```

A simple read loop can read in the data generated by each button press like so:

```
char c;
while (read(0, &c, 1) != -1) { PRINT_CHAR(c); }
```

Now,

- Pressing Esc on my keyboard generates: 0x1b.
- Pressing F1 generates: 0x1b 0x4f 0x50.
- Pressing F5 generates: 0x1b 0x5b 0x31 0x35 0x7e.

In terms of reading and processing this input, how does one determine where the output from one button press ends and the next one begins? I could find no discernible pattern, and the fact that Esc generates a single byte which is also identical to the first byte of output for most multi-byte generating button presses seems to suggest there is none. Is there some other mechanism for determining where the button boundaries are?

Answer (score 2):

Programs rely on keys not being pressed too fast. If the delay is less than say 100ms, this is one key press; otherwise there are two separate events.

Yes program actually pause for some time after ESC is being pressed, in order to make sure it's ESC and no some other key. Sometimes this pause can be discerned with the naked eye.

Some programs recognize the ESCDELAY environment variable for fine-tuning this timing.

And yes this is not perfect, you can fool the system by pressing keys too fast.

Comment: Is this what curses does in order to recognize individual keys?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK it does (and it has ESCDELAY global variable (as in C, not as in shell) you can set to control this).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, thanks to n.m., I was set on the right track here.

Trying to read one byte at a time is incorrect. Rather one should attempt to read multiple characters at once.

Something like the following:

```
int r, i;
char buffer[10]; //10 chosen arbitrarily
while ((r = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) != -1)
{
  printf("%d bytes: ", r);
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i) { PRINT_CHAR(buffer[i]); }
  printf("\r\n");
}
```

In this case, the read() call will return as soon as a button is pressed, and will return the amount of bytes read. Now the bytes can be used to identify the button or character in question.

Pressing the top row of buttons using above loop, I'm seeing:

```
1 bytes: 1b
3 bytes: 1b 4f 50
3 bytes: 1b 4f 51
3 bytes: 1b 4f 52
3 bytes: 1b 4f 53
5 bytes: 1b 5b 31 35 7e
5 bytes: 1b 5b 31 37 7e
```

On my machine, I appear to be getting:

- A single byte for ASCII characters.
- 0x1b as the first character, followed by other characters for special buttons (F1-F12, Up, Down, etc...).
- Some other multi-byte sequence for non ASCII characters, which turns out to be the UTF-8 representation of the character in question.

I tried jamming down the buttons on my keyboard like a mad man, but the above loop was always able to identify correctly which bytes are a single unit.

However this may not work completely as desired on a heavily taxed machine, or over a buffered high latency network connection. Perhaps in those situations, more bytes from multiple latter button presses will have already found themselves in the terminal buffer, causing multiple buttons to appear as one.

In such a situation, there probably is no way to ensure errors won't occur, however they can be minimized. Single byte characters always appear to be in the range of 0x00-0x7F. Special buttons are always multi-byte and begin with 0x1B followed by something within 0x00-0x7F. Multi-byte characters are always in the range 0x80-0xFF. The UTF-8 encoding sequence also has the first byte indicate how many bytes are in the current character. Given this information, there's enough to ensure errors are minimal and do not propagate to upcoming reads unnecessarily.

Lastly, it's important to stress that what I described is for my machine (PC, classic US 101 keyboard, Terminal encoding set to UTF-8). A full program should minimally see what character encoding the terminal is using.

Comment: Expecting bulk delivery in a single read() call will not be reliable over a serial (or other remote) terminal connection - and that's what these codes date from.

Comment: No, in those cases, we need to follow a timing system as n.m. explained, and in cases where there's too much bulk is already covered in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you must determine these by context.  Based on the characters you receive after the escape, you can determine the overall sequence length of known sequences, then return to interpreting characters normally.

You should be able to look up the escape sequences for known terminals.

It is possible some of your function keys have locally configured expansions, especially if they do not match the codes for whatever variety of standard terminal is otherwise implemented.

Comment: That can't possibly be right. F1 generates 0x1b 0x4f 0x50 which is also generated by pressing Esc, O, P. How does one determine if one is seeing 3 individual keys or a single key using an escape sequence?

Comment: If the user presses those keys in sequence the escape sequence should be activated.  That's the point of an escape key.

Comment: In `vim` using a VT100-compatible terminal emulator, will Esc+O+A keys move up one line or insert a line? (The answer is: it depends on how fast you are pressing them).